# Compare n no of column values between each record in 2 files and apend data from file 2 to file 1

Tags: bash

I have an input file like this:

Example for input file:

```
a|a1|a2|a3|a4|a5|...|a29|$2342
a|a1|a2|a3|a4|a5|...|a29|$2343
a|a1|a2|a3|a4|a5|...|a29|$2344
a|a1|a2|a3|a4|a5|...|a29|$2345
b|b1|b2|b3|b4|b5|...|b29|$100
c|c1|c2|c3|c4|c5|...|c29|$12
```

And another file has data like this:

```
a|a1|a2|a3|a4|a5|...|a29|$2342|123|1.0|21.0
b|b1|b2|b3|b4|b5|...|b29|$100|12567|16.0|31.0
c|c1|c2|c3|c4|c5|...|c29|$12|6213|1.9|1.1
```

I am trying to get the final output using these two files as mentioned below:

```
a|a1|a2|a3|a4|a5|...|a29|$2342|123|1.0|21.0
a|a1|a2|a3|a4|a5|...|a29|$2343|123|1.0|21.0
a|a1|a2|a3|a4|a5|...|a29|$2344|123|1.0|21.0
a|a1|a2|a3|a4|a5|...|a29|$2345|123|1.0|21.0
b|b1|b2|b3|b4|b5|...|b29|$100|12567|16.0|31.0
c|c1|c2|c3|c4|c5|...|c29|$12|6213|1.9|1.1
```

I think if we can compare the column before `#` value and if found to be same then append value from 2nd file into 1st one.

Comment: @ Janis: How can we achive this? And yes I need to check the column values till the value " # " and if same then append the values.

Comment: I just edited your post for legibility. Now await answers from the community.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical task for `awk`. Here is one possible solution:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
    match($0,/.*\$/)
    pref = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    rest = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    suff = substr(rest, index(rest,"|"))
    suffixes[pref] = suff
    next
}
{
    match($0,/.*\$/)
    prefix = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    match($0,/.*\$[0-9]+|/)
    data = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    if (prefix in suffixes)
        print data suffixes[prefix]
}
' file2 file1
```

where `file1` is the one named "input file" in your question, and `file2` the one named "another file" in your question. (Mind the ordering of the files in the list.)

Explanation:

The first command block is executed while reading the first file `file2`; this is achieved by the condition `NR==FNR` which is only true while the first file is read. The second command block is executed only for the second file `file1` (because of the `next` directive in the first command block). The first block extracts the prefix `pref` and the suffix `suff`, and `suffixes[pref] = suff` memorizes for each prefix the corresponding suffix; this is necessary to refer to that data in the second block. In the second block there's actually similar commands executed to extract the prefix, and to use it to get from the stored suffixes the right suffix. There's only one other difference; you need to also keep the number after the `#` symbol as part of your new prefix data, so there's a second `match` operation; to distinguish the prefix necessary to access the array `suffixes` from the prefix that's necessary as part of the result data.

Comment: Could you please explain the steps as well?

Comment: @mdx: I've added an Explanation section.

Comment: I have used the same code just put my file names and replaced # with $ sign. but it doesn't give any output.

Code used:

awk '
NR==FNR {
    match($0,/.*$/)
    pref = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    rest = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    suff = substr(rest, index(rest,"|"))
    suffixes[pref] = suff
    next
}
{
    match($0,/.*$/)
    prefix = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    match($0,/.*$[0-9]+|/)
    data = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    if (prefix in suffixes)
        print data suffixes[prefix]
}
' dup-file.txt.out actual-input-file.txt

Comment: could you please suggest the reason i am getting no output out this code?

Comment: @mdx; maybe you made a copy/paste error, or maybe you aplied the files in the wrong order; who knows? - All I can say is that I checked the code with your data, and the code conforms to the `awk` standard. So re-examine what you've actually done.

Comment: Wait! - I've just read your former comment. - Why did you change `#` to `$`, may I ask? In your data samples you showed that there are `#` in the data, but no `$`. - `$` has a specific meaning in the regular expressions; it means end of line or end of field. (In case you want to match a literal `$` you would have to escape it with a backslash: `\$`.)

Comment: Janis, I have changed '#' to '$'. so what changed would be required in your code above?

Comment: Sorry for that. But i got to know that we need $ instead of #.

Comment: Assuming you have changed the `#` consistently to `$` in the proposed code **and** in your data, then escape the `$` as `\$`. - Let me know if that fixes the effects of your data change.

Comment: So i will just copy the code mentioned above and replace # by \$, is that correct?

Comment: Correct; it's the three occurrences in the `match` functions. - If it works as desired and if you update your question I'll also adjust the answer accordingly.

Comment: It worked Buddy. Thanks a Ton!!!!!!! You rock.

Comment: One more silly question, how can i accept this answer. Not awre of the correct options here.

Comment: Frankly, I can't tell you; I've only had three questions posted in the past and none could be answered. - But I suppose you should see a button or a link that's named "accept" or so. No? (I know you need some reputation to be able to vote, but I'd have thought that accepting an answer to an own question should be possible.)